# How solved "R cannot be resolved to a variable" in eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse

When I try to run a java project, a message appears after it finishes to run:

[image]

> R cannot be resolved to a variable

I tried to clean the project and rebuild it but the error still remains.

Comment: by providing the R class to the classpath. you may want to learn how to post a decent question

Comment: Well, not using a deprecated IDE for Android  developing would be a good start

Comment: Rebuild your project

Comment: import the R file that is belonging to your project.

Comment: but why are you not using android studio?

Answer (score 2):

Check your xml files. you have an error somewhere in one of them. fix it then clean/build project.

Comment: Send my xml file:

<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.roadtrack.primatest"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="10"
        android:targetSdkVersion="10" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    </application>

</manifest>

Comment: is this the only xml file in your project ? you don't have layouts? resources? i mean strings.xml and others.. you need to check also those files. give me a feedback after check.

Answer (score 0):

In Android project the R class should be automatically generated after clean buid if your configuration is right.